# Como detectar quando eu aperto uma tecla

Tags: python, teclado

Acho que o título ficou meio confuso, mas é o seguinte:
Eu quero que quando eu aperte a tecla 'e', uma variavel minha se torne True, e quando eu apertar essa mesma tecla novamente, essa mesma variavel se torna False.
O problema é que, eu tou usando a função `keyboard.is_pressed('e')`.
Exemplo:

```
import keyboard as kb

while True:
    if kb.is_pressed('e'):
        print('Pressionou e')
```

O que eu quero: que o print só seja acionado uma vez, mesmo que eu segurar a tecla 'e', por exemplo:
Mesmo se eu apertar e segurar a tecla E, o print só vai aparecer uma vez, aí eu teria que soltar a tecla E e apertar novamente, aí aparecia o print novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o ideal seria usar a lógica do liga/desliga.
Criar uma variável considerando a última ação, conforme código a baixo:

```
import keyboard as kb

pressionou = False

while pressionou == False:
    if kb.is_pressed('e'):
        pressionou = True
        print('Pressionou e')
```

Comment: Entendi, mas nessa lógica, a variável 'pressionou' irá ficar True apenas enquanto eu estiver segurando a tecla 'e', se eu soltar a tecla 'e', a variavel vira False

Answer (score -1):

Tem como colocar outro `while` dentro do `if` pra verificar se a tecla ainda está sendo pressionada:

```py
import keyboard as kb

while True:
    if kb.is_pressed('e'):
        print('Pressionado E')
        while kb.is_pressed('e'):
            continue
```

Answer (score -2):

Só usar um /break, por exemplo
Import keyboard as kb
While True:
If kb.is_pressed('a'):
Print('Pressionou e')
break